# Informatica, Create new table with input from another table

Tags: sql, informatica

I want to create a new table in informatica using values from another table.
For example, If I have a table which contains fields like variable name, variable type. I want to use these two values in my create statement somehow to create a new table.
Any idea how to go about it. Thank you!

Example:

```
Input table rows:
First_Name, varchar
Second_Name, varchar
ID, int
```

Output table after creation should have columns First_name of type varchar,
Something like

```
Create Table new1,
(First_name varchar,
Second_name varchar,
ID int)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is tge structure of your real table?

Comment: Do you mean the input table by the real table?

Comment: Yes. Please post the input table's structure

Comment: oh yeah, so the input table has columns which provide
-- Variable Name
-- Variable Type 
For example:
1st row - First_Name, varchar

Comment: I think you need to use dynamic SQL. Checkout this link. https://marketplace.informatica.com/solutions/dynamic_sql_transformation

Comment: Are you creating the table in a different db / schema?

Comment: Thank you @AnkurPatel, I will check it out.

Comment: Hey @DanielMachet, No it's in the same schema. But I am still struggling with it

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what I understand is you have columns with the attributes needed to create a table like Column_name and Column_DataType.

You can perform the below steps:

Step 1: Normalize the data and change rows to column.

Step 2: Concat the newly created column to create the query you needed.

Step 3: Store the newly created query in a mapping variable.

Step 4: Assign the above mentioned mapping variable to a workflow variable in a session.

Step 5: Write the above worklow variable in the pre sql/post sql of session and the query will get executed and the table would be created.

Comment: Hey @Prashant, thank you for your reply it helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

So all you need is an sql along the lines of
    CREATE TABLE TABLE2 AS SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE 1=2;

No need for mapping logic in this one

Comment: Hey @Daniel, thank you for the reply. I tried implementing solutions but couldn't figure it out so changed the usecase